# "The type TraceWriter must derive from ITraceWriter" after upgrading to Web API 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, upgrade, asp.net-web-api2, trace

We have a custom Web API **ITraceWriter** implementation named **TraceWriter**, registered as a service in the usual way in Application_Start.

After upgrading the Web API project to Web API 2, an HttpException is thrown in Application_Start:

```
The type TraceWriter must derive from ITraceWriter.
Parameter name: service
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ServicesContainer.Replace(Type serviceType, Object service)
```

Of course, the TraceWriter actually is deriving from ITraceWriter, so what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TraceWriter implementation was located in a different project, which still referenced **System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0**. Installing the latest **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core** package in this project solved the problem.

Comment: I got caught by this by already having "using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization"; in the class.  This also has an ITraceWriter.